# SQL command for STR(<number>,<m>,<n>) FoxPro command

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, foxpro

I'm new to SQL and looking for the SQL command for `STR(<number>,<m>,<n>)` (return  as a string of `<m>` characters rounded to `<n>` decimals) `FoxPro` command ([description of FoxPro command](http://www.alvechurchdata.co.uk/foxtext.htm)).

### Edited

I need to convert this FoxPro command `substr(str(borrower,9,0),1,1)` to a SQL command.

Comment: Why would you want to get the first digit of a number? What is the purpose of that expression?

Answer (score 1):

Since SQLite 3.8.3, you can use the [printf() function](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#printf):

```
> SELECT '|' || printf('%10.1f', 123.456) || '|';
|     123.5|
```

But if you want to be portable, you should format the numbers in your program.

Answer (score 1):

```
Cast(Round(number,n), As VARCHAR(m))
```

In your case the sql command will be:

Update::

```
 SUBSTR( CAST(ROUND(borrower,0) AS  varchar(10)),1,1)
```

Comment: I have updated the answer please check, this time i have tested.

Comment: The internal ROUND should not be needed, unless you want values of 0.5 to 0.99... to show as 1 and not 0.